# Windows phone freezes up during network requests if there is no reception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, google-analytics, windows-phone, freeze

I've integrated Google Analytics and Flurry into the game I am working (WP8 and MonoGame stack). 
It is working perfectly, when the device have a good reception, however it freezes up intermittently if there is no reception (say, when I am in the subway). This deteriorates user experience greatly.

I've also noticed the same behaviour of the phone, if I have a mail to send in the outbox of the standard WP8 email client.

The freezes happen even when I am not submitting data to the GA or Flurry. It seems that GA background retry job kicks in, which is causing freezes.

I wonder if there is acceptable workaround available?

Here what I have found so far:

Seems like GA library supports `IsConnected` property ([source code](http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GoogleAnalytics.Common/GAServiceManager.cs)). If it is offline, it queues up all requests to send them later. However, I don't know which method to use to determine in a non-blocking way if data connection is available.